# Encrypting the password before authetication

Tags: spring-security, spring-integration, spring-ws

I have to authenticate a SOAP message that sends passwords in plain text with the encrypted password from the database.  We use HTTPS for all traffic so the entire message in encrypted.

Anyway, I have implemented the following SI configuration, which works until Spring tries to match the passwords.  Since the SOAP password is plain text and the db passowrd is encrypted, I must encrypt the password before Spring authenticates.  I have service methods to do this already implemented.

```
<bean id="SOAPSecurityValidationCallbackHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SpringSecurityPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
   <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.ps.snt.ws.security.SNTUserDetailsService" />
```

UserDetailsService implementation:

```
 public class SNTUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

            System.out.println("In security callback " + username);

            boolean valid = true;
            Integer zoneID = null;

            StringBuffer errorMessages = new StringBuffer();

            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
                // TODO wil lthis ever happen, does framework check first?
                errorMessages.append("Username token cannot be empty");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\w]+@+\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(username);
                if(!matcher.matches()) {
                    valid = false;
                    errorMessages.append("Username token must be in the format 'user@zone'.");
                }
                else {
                    String[] parts = username.split("@");
                    username = parts[0];
                    zoneID = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                }
            }

            if(valid && username != null && zoneID != null) {
                LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
                ApplicationUserDO user = loginService.getUserByUsername(zoneID.toString(), username);

                boolean enabled = true;
                boolean accountNonExpired = true;
                boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
                boolean accountNonLocked = true;

                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

                grantedAuths.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));

                UserDetails userDetails = new User(user.getUsername(), 
                        user.getPassword(), 
                        enabled, 
                        accountNonExpired, 
                        credentialsNonExpired, 
                        accountNonLocked, 
                        grantedAuths );

                return userDetails;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Authetnication failed!");
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Epic fail!"); 
            }

        }
    }
```

The user details service does what its supposed to - it returns a user with the password from the database.

I tried overidding handleUSernameTokenPrincipal in SpringSecurityPasswordValidationCallbackHandler to set the password to the encrypted version, but this method never gets called.  Overriding handleUsername is not useful as I do not have access to the original password.

I would like to keep the details service and use this callback, but I need to set the password in the principal to the encrypted version before authentication.

Ideally I would want to set the password after validation of the SOAP header but before the user details service is called.  Not sure if I can do this with another interceptor, but I do not want to parse through XML and et it that way.  I would like to do it in a somewhat safe manner.

Comment: How you solve this issue? I'm also facing same issues? pls help

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using an authentication manager on the callback:

```
<bean id="SOAPSecurityValidationCallbackHandler"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="CommonAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>
```

The AuthenticationManager interface must implement one method - authenticate:

```
public class CommonAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager  {

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = auth.getName();
        String password = (String) auth.getCredentials();

        ... encrypt password
        ... validate against DB

        // this will be available in the message flow to any channel
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getName(),
                auth.getCredentials(), grantedAuths);

    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I am not sure how we can call CommonAuthenticationManager in order to get Plaintext from AuthenticationManager. Could you please help ? We're using WS version 2.1.0. Please provide whole XML file for our reference.